# Is 'The corridors flood with teenage noise, energy and emotion' a correct sentence?

Tags: active-vs-passive

Is 'The corridors flood with teenage noise, energy and emotion' a correct sentence?
I say this in a passage but I think the correct version will be 'The corridorrs are flooded with teenage noise, energy and emotion'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically, both versions are fine, and broadly speaking they mean the same. But *idiomatically, stylistically*, the "passive" (second) version would normally be preferred.

Arguably, the "active" (first) version may carry slightly stronger implications of "directed activity". That's to say, there's a stronger allusion to something *causing* the metaphorical flood, whereas the passive version focuses more on ***describing*** the flood.

---

Shifting to the more natural *past* tense, and simplfying, we have...

> 1: *The room flooded with light*  (stylised, "poetic")
>    2: *The room was flooded with light*  (normal descriptive prose style)

...where #1 might more naturally imply ***...when he opened the curtains***, as opposed to simply reporting the fact that the room was brightly lit.

Note that this (possible) distinction can only arise because semantically it's possible to *flood [some place] **with** [something]*. If we switch to a different verb, such as...

> 3: *The garden teemed with life*
>    4: *The garden was teeming with life*

...then I don't think it's meaningful to attempt to draw even a slight semantic distinction. But I still think the "active" version #3 is a bit more stylised / literary than passive #4.

Comment: sorry for very late reply, but if I have to say "The corridors are flooded with teenage noise, energy and emotion" in active voice, shouldn't it be "Teenage noise, energy and emotion flood the corridors"?

Comment: @LearningMathematics: ***to flood*** is a "2-way" kind of verb, so it's okay to say *The room flooded with light* ("active") OR *The room **was** flooded with light* ("passive") OR *Light flooded the room* (another "active" usage, but with a different "subject"). You can't do that with my other example (*Life teemed the garden* isn't valid, but preposition-based *Life teemed **in** the garden* is at least "acceptable", even if it's not particularly likely compared to *The garden teemed **with** life*).